# Python Requests: use default form value

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm migrating from Mechanize to Requests because Mechanize isn't supported yet in Python 3.x. I've come up with this simple script to post data, but the returned page shows an error:  Error: Can't load FIXES database!

```
url = "http://rfinder.asalink.net/free/"
payload = {"id1": "EGLL", "id2": "LOWW"}
r = requests.post(url, payload)
```

Using mechanize I only had to post the `id1` and `id2` fields and submit the form. All other fields were default.

I think this is where things go wrong. How do I tell Requests to post all the default data + the `id1` and `id2` fields?

Comment: Requests is only an HTTP client library and can't parse and HTML form to get its default field names and values from. You should either manually hardcode those fields in your script or use an HTML parser like BeautifulSoup to parse the form each time and extract field names & default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example with the hard-coded fields:

```
import requests

url = "http://rfinder.asalink.net/free/autoroute_rtx.php"

payload = {
    'id1':'lirf',
    'ic1':'',
    'id2':'egll',
    'ic2':'',
    'minalt':'FL330',
    'maxalt':'FL330',
    'lvl':'B',
    'dbid':1408,
    'usesid':'Y',
    'usestar':'Y',
    'easet':'Y',
    'rnav':'Y',
    'nats':'',
    'k':235644007
}

r = requests.post(url, data=payload)

print( r.text )
```